# how to make a telegram bot with rasa deployed on heroku

Tags: heroku, telegram, chatbot, rasa

I have created a chatbot using the rasa framework and have deployed it to heroku, how do I make chatbot usable on telegram

Answer (score 0):

Using Telegram with Rasa Open Source is described in the [documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/telegram).

You have to add the following to your `credentials.yml` file before running Rasa Open Source with `rasa run`:

```
telegram:
  access_token: "490161424:AAGlRxinBRtKGb21_rlOEMtDFZMXBl6EC0o"
  verify: "your_bot"
  webhook_url: "https://your_url.com/webhooks/telegram/webhook"
```

`webhook_url` should use the hostname / IP of your Heroku server.

Comment: error occurs when I change webhook_url to hostname of heroku server,
the error is "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail "